# Taskbar for X11 using Athena widgets

Tags: c, gui, x11

I am developing a simple taskbar for X11 using the Athena widgets. The current code is very limited: it assumes an EWMH-compliant window manager and only adds the initially running windows to the taskbar. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The program depends on the libX11, libXt and libXaw development packages. It can be compiled with:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs x11 xaw7` -o xpanel xpanel.c
```

## xpanel.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
#include <X11/Shell.h>
#include <X11/StringDefs.h>
#include <X11/Xaw/Box.h>
#include <X11/Xaw/Command.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

/* used as return values for functions */
enum status {
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE
};

static char *atom_names[] = {
    "WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
    "_NET_CLIENT_LIST",
    "_NET_WM_NAME",
};

enum {
    WM_DELETE_WINDOW,
    NET_CLIENT_LIST,
    NET_WM_NAME,
    ATOM_COUNT
};

/* the X server variables are kept in a global struct */
struct app_data {
    Display *display;
    XtAppContext    app_context;
    Widget  app_shell;
    Window  root_window;
    Atom    atoms[ATOM_COUNT];
    Window  main_window;
};

struct app_data app_data;

/* the tasks (application windows) are organized as a linked list of structs */
struct task {
    struct task *next_task;
    Window  window;
    char    *title;
    Widget  button;
};

struct task_list {
    struct task *first_task;
    struct task *last_task;
};

/* this gets the list of currently open application windows */
enum status get_window_list(Window **window_list, long unsigned int *window_count) {
    Atom actual_type;
    int item_size;
    unsigned long leftover_byte_count;

    /* max. size 256L: 256 x 4-byte multiples = 1 MB */
    if (XGetWindowProperty(app_data.display, app_data.root_window, app_data.atoms[NET_CLIENT_LIST], 0L, 256L, False, XA_WINDOW, &actual_type, &item_size, window_count, &leftover_byte_count, (unsigned char **) window_list) != Success || window_count == 0) {
        fputs("Could not get window list property.\n", stderr); return FAILURE;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status get_window_title(Window window, char **window_title) {
    enum status return_code = FAILURE;

    XTextProperty text_property;
    char **text_list = NULL;

    if (XGetTextProperty(app_data.display, window, &text_property, app_data.atoms[NET_WM_NAME]) == 0) {
        if (XGetWMName(app_data.display, window, &text_property) == 0) {
            fputs("Could not get window title property.\n", stderr); goto out;
        }
    }

    /* the text property is converted to a text list to convert it to the encoding of the current locale */
    int string_count = 0;
    XmbTextPropertyToTextList(app_data.display, &text_property, &text_list, &string_count);

    size_t buffer_size = strlen(text_list[0]) + 1;
    *window_title = malloc(buffer_size);
    if (window_title == NULL) {
        perror("malloc"); goto out;
    }
    memcpy(*window_title, text_list[0], buffer_size);

    return_code = SUCCESS;

    out:
        XFree(text_property.value);
        XFreeStringList(text_list);
        return return_code;
}

void button_callback(Widget button, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data) {
    XRaiseWindow(app_data.display, (Window) client_data);
    XSetInputFocus(app_data.display, (Window) client_data, RevertToParent, CurrentTime);
}

/* this fills the variables of a task struct */
void initialize_task(Widget taskbar, Window window, struct task *task) {
    task->window = window;

    char *window_title = NULL;
    if (get_window_title(window, &window_title) == SUCCESS) {
        task->title = window_title;
    } else {
        task->title = "<No Title>";
    }

    task->button = XtVaCreateWidget(NULL, commandWidgetClass, taskbar, XtNlabel, window_title, NULL);
    XtAddCallback(task->button, XtNcallback, button_callback, (XtPointer)window);
}

/* this appends a task struct to the linked list */
void append_task(struct task_list *task_list, struct task *task) {
    task->next_task = NULL;

    if (task_list->first_task == NULL) { // list is empty
        task_list->first_task = task_list->last_task = task;
    } else {
        task_list->last_task->next_task = task;
        task_list->last_task = task;
    }
}

/* this gets the list of currently running windows, creates a task struct including a button widget for each of them, appends the structs to the linked list and adds the buttons to the taskbar */
enum status initialize_task_list(Widget taskbar, struct task_list *task_list) {
    enum status return_code = FAILURE;

    Window *window_list;
    long unsigned int window_list_size;
    if (get_window_list(&window_list, &window_list_size) == FAILURE) {
        fputs("Could not get window list.\n", stderr); goto out;
    }

    /* the task buttons are collected in a dynamically resized array */
    int button_array_capacity = 32;
    Widget *button_array = malloc(button_array_capacity * sizeof *button_array);
    if (button_array == NULL) {
        perror("malloc"); goto out;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < window_list_size; i++) {
        struct task *new_task = malloc(sizeof *new_task);
        if (new_task == NULL) {
            perror("malloc"); goto out;
        }

        initialize_task(taskbar, window_list[i], new_task);

        if(i == button_array_capacity) {
            button_array_capacity = button_array_capacity + (button_array_capacity >> 1); // growth factor = 1.5
            Widget *new_button_array = realloc(button_array, button_array_capacity * sizeof *button_array);
            if (new_button_array == NULL) {
                perror("realloc"); goto out;
            }
            button_array = new_button_array;
        }
        button_array[i] = new_task->button;

        append_task(task_list, new_task);
    }

    XtManageChildren((Widget *) button_array, window_list_size);
    return_code = SUCCESS;

    out:
        XFree(window_list);
        free(button_array);
        return return_code;
}

/* this handles window manager events (at the moment only requests for deletion of our own window) */
void wm_event_handler(Widget widget, XtPointer client_data, XEvent *event, Boolean *continue_dispatch) {
    if ((event->type == ClientMessage) && (event->xclient.data.l[0] == app_data.atoms[WM_DELETE_WINDOW])) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

void initialize_x11(struct app_data *app_data, int *argc, char **argv) {
    app_data->app_shell = XtVaOpenApplication(&(app_data->app_context), "XPanel", NULL, 0, argc, argv, NULL, applicationShellWidgetClass, XtNwidth, 800, XtNheight, 50, NULL);
    app_data->display = XtDisplay(app_data->app_shell);
    app_data->root_window = DefaultRootWindow(app_data->display);
    XInternAtoms(app_data->display, atom_names, ATOM_COUNT, False, app_data->atoms);

    XtRealizeWidget(app_data->app_shell);
    app_data->main_window = XtWindow(app_data->app_shell);

    XSetWMProtocols(app_data->display, app_data->main_window, &(app_data->atoms[WM_DELETE_WINDOW]), 1);
    XtAddEventHandler(app_data->app_shell, NoEventMask, True, &wm_event_handler, NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

    initialize_x11(&app_data, &argc, argv);

    Widget taskbar = XtVaCreateManagedWidget("taskbar", boxWidgetClass, app_data.app_shell, XtNorientation, XtorientHorizontal, NULL);
    struct task_list task_list = {0};
    initialize_task_list(taskbar, &task_list);

    XtAppMainLoop(app_data.app_context);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## Questions

I wonder whether it is a good idea to keep the X11 variables in a global struct. Without global variables, it would be necessary to pass a struct or several independent X11 variables through the nested functions `initialize_task_list`, `initialize_task`, `get_window_list`, `get_window_title` and `XtAddCallback`. As `XtAddCallback` accepts only a single pointer to user-defined data, I would also need an additional callback data struct to pass the `display` and `window` variables to the button callback procedure.

What else do you think about my code? What could be improved? I appreciate any comments or suggestions!

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, it occasionally „freezes”. Not sure, what can be the reason.
2. I wonder, how would you add key event handler — for example to allow instant close of the application by „Escape” key-press?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have the opportunity to test this code right now, but you did ask specifically about `app_data` being global.  So I’ll address that narrow issue.

This question usually gets closed on StackOverflow as “opinion-based.”  It’s *generally* considered a bad idea to have mutable global state (not thread-safe, hard to diagnose and reproduce bugs caused by modifying it in another part of the program).  However, turning the global state into “tramp data” that gets passed from one function to another to another to another is either very inefficient (if the data is copied on each call) or no safer (if it is passed around by mutable reference).  And it can get ugly.

In this case, though, if you don’t need to modify `app_data` after `initialize_x11()` sets it, you could move both `app_data` and `initialize_x11()` to a separate source file, with an accompanying header file that declares

```
extern const struct app_data_t app_data;
```

Instead of taking `&app_data` as a parameter, `initialize_x11()` would now set the global variable in its own module, which any other module that includes the header can read but not modify.  This might or might not work for the full app, but I do not see any line modifying `app_data` after it is initialized.  This might just be because you say it doesn’t check for changes to the list of running apps.

If you’re always checking for updates to that, you want a function that returns the current list (which might cache it as `static` data).  If, for example, your app listens for notifications that a program has opened or closed on the display, one solution might be a `static` list, a function to add a new program to the list, a function to remove one from the list, and a function to return a copy of the list, all in the same module.  Another would be a reader-writer lock.  Or if your app is single-threaded, you don’t need to worry about thread safety, but it’s still good practice to put all the code that modifies this global data in a single module.

Global constants are perfectly fine!  There’s no danger of one part of the program modifying their state in a way that breaks another part.

It’s a bad idea to give a variable and a type the same name, by the way, and this would not even compile if you tried to use this in a C++ program.  I therefore suggest renaming `struct app_data` to something like `struct app_data_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`atom_names` is initialised from string literals, so needs to be an array of pointer to *const* char:

```
static char const *atom_names[]
```

Similarly, `task`'s `title` needs to point to const char.

We can eliminate compiler warnings for the unused parameters, by mentioning them in the function:

```
void button_callback(Widget button, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data) {
    (void)button;
    (void)call_data;
```

We have problematic conversion between signed and unsigned integer types here:

> ```
> int button_array_capacity = 32;
> Widget *button_array = malloc(button_array_capacity * sizeof *button_array);
> ```

That's easily avoidable by using `unsigned int` for the capacity.

Similarly, make the loop index `i` match `window_list_size`:

```
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < window_list_size; i++) {
```

There's a pointless cast here, since `button_array` is a `Widget*` already:

> ```
> XtManageChildren((Widget *) button_array, window_list_size);
> ```

On the other hand, we should have a cast for the narrowing conversion of `window_list_size`.

As these are all problems that were detected by compilation, I presume you are not enabling a sufficient set of warnings.  I used `gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion -Wuseless-cast  -Wstrict-prototypes -fanalyzer  -Wconversion` (but note that `-fanalyzer` seems to give false positives where `goto` is used to jump to the error exit - that may be worth a bug report).

---

On the positive, I like the thought given to detecting and reporting errors (though we seem to ignore the return value from `initialize_task_list()` in our main function - if that's intentional, it's worth a comment).